# c++17 memory access of memory owned by c++11 library

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I have a program compiled with -std=c++17 and it links against a library that uses -std=c++11. There is a class with a buffer (char *) inside the c++11 that I want to use. The c++11 library made the buffer public for whatever reason. When I look at this buffer from my class in the c++17 program, the buffer is pointing 4 bytes too far. So  I am missing 4 bytes. If I step into the class from the c++11 library and I look at the buffer it looks fine. I want to know if this is a known thing between c++17 as i don't normally mix and match c++ versions.

Here is what I see in gdb when stepping through the code below.

```
(gdb) p &bufClass.buf
$11 = (unsigned char (*)[4194304]) 0x7fffffbf9efc
(then ill step into the print())
(gdb) p &buf
$12 = (unsigned char (*)[4194304]) 0x7fffffbf9ef8
```

Here is a rough idea of what it looks like:

```
#include "theirlib.h"
class MyClass
{
public:
void inspectbuff()
{
std::cout.write(bufClass.buf, 8); //"OYOU\0\0\0\0"
bufClass.print(std::cout); //this is a function implemeted in that lib and buf-> "HELLOYOU"
}

private:
theirlib::theirclass bufClass;
};
```

Comment: Impossible to guess. It's most probably not related to the compiler version but some alignment option?

Comment: What is that second argument `8`? It seems to me it is acting as a byte offset and characters are consuming 2 bytes each so you skip `HELL` and then it goes off the buffer's end, possible UB.

Comment: @TanveerBadar you can ignore the code, I am using gdb to print the memroy directly. Let me add what I see in gdb.

Comment: The degree to which libraries compiled with different flags can interoperate depends on the compiler toolchain you are using. There are sometimes ABI breaking changes between versions.

Comment: @RaymondChen g++ (GCC) 8.3.1 20190311 (Red Hat 8.3.1-3) for c++17 and g++ (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6) for c++11

Comment: You'll have to check the documentation for those compilers to see what interoperability/breaking changes. But the proof is right in front of you: For the `theirclass` class, the layout changed. You could investigate that class to see what specifically changed. Maybe the class contains a standard library type whose size changed between C++11 and C++17.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks let me look at that. Just as an update, i ended up recompiling the c++11 library with c++17 and everything looks good now. So definitely mixing the two versions is the issue. Hopefully I can figure out the issue, otherwise I will have to downgrade my application, looks like we're not ready for c++17.

Comment: [Here is the gcc documentation on library breaking changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html). Interoperability is not supported between libraries of different major versions.

Comment: @sdstack an alternative to sticking to C++11 for your whole program would be to write a wrapper around the external library. The wrapper must be compiled with C++11 and must not expose or use any non-integral types in its API. Allocations, accesses and deallocations  must all be done within the wrapper. That way you can separate the different ABIs.